# Why does this pattern fail to match?

Tags: pattern-matching

I'd like to replace fractions with `Missing[]` as the denominator with `Missing[]`. This pattern in `ReplaceAll` does not do the job:

```
ReplaceAll[{1/Missing[], 2}, (_/Missing[] :> Missing[])]
```

But the exact match works fine:

```
ReplaceAll[{1/Missing[], 2}, (1/Missing[] :> Missing[])]
```

Why is this?

Comment: In the interest of helping you help yourself: look at `FullForm[{1/Missing[], _/Missing[]}]`. It should be quickly apparent why you're not getting what you want.

Comment: ...and since you're matching denominators only: you know there's a `Denominator[]` function, yes?

Comment: As an extension to the comments above , `{a/Missing[ ],2}/. _/Missing[]:>Missing[ ]` will work for any  `a` .... except `1` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using the optional value in the pattern, there is no special case:

```
ReplaceAll[{1/Missing[], 2/Missing[], 3}, _./Missing[] :> Missing[]]

(* {Missing[], Missing[], 3} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

`1/Missing[]` is a special case, equivalent to `Missing[]^-1`. This is why the original pattern matches `2/Missing[]`. I guess the best way is to handle it separately:

```
ReplaceAll[{1/Missing[], 2/Missing[], 3}, {_/Missing[] :> Missing[], 1/Missing[] :> Missing[]}]
```

(Thanks to J.M. and belisarius for the hints.)

Comment: Actually, I'd have done `{1/Missing[], 2/Missing[], 3} /. x_ /; Denominator[x] === Missing[] :> Missing[]`. ;)